# How to replace special chars with preg_replace and PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters

Let say we have random string like this:

> $str_test = "faafŠ š čćž đš čšđ ćčš žž fa fssfa afž afžsa f";

and we do some preg_replace function on it:

```
preg_replace("/[^\da-z ]/i", "_", $str_test);
```

And the result I get is:

```
faaf__ __ ______ ____ ______ ______ ____ fa fssfa af__ af__sa f
```

So if we compare bothe - input and output:

```
faaf__ __ ______ ____ ______ ______ ____ fa fssfa af__ af__sa f
faafŠ š čćž đš čšđ ćčš žž fa fssfa afž afžsa f
```

we can see that all special chars are being replaced with two signt "_" ... Result should be:

```
faaf_ _ ___ __ ___ ___ __ fa fssfa af_ af_sa f
faafŠ š čćž đš čšđ ćčš žž fa fssfa afž afžsa f
```

I have tried with encodings already but no success.. I also thought to make function to do multiple preg_match once and than replace "_*" with "*" ... but that would be slow on big texts ...

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try `/[^\da-z ]{1, 2}/i`?

Comment: 1). make sure is your php file has utf-8 encoding wihout BOM. 2). in preg_replace function set flag to deal with this as unicode small letter 'u' after last slash '/' or 'i' flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str=preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/u", "_", $str_test);
```

Notice 'u' modifier! Explanation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#107498

```
If the _subject_ contains utf-8 sequences the 'u' modifier should be set, otherwise a pattern such as /./ could match a utf-8 *sequence as two to four individual ASCII characters*.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the build in php multibyte functions?

`mb_ereg_replace` is the one to use here. [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php)